JPanel no muestra nada
Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en Java que cuenta con una interfaz de usuario para iniciar sesión. Estoy trabajando con Java SWING para implementar esta interfaz gráfica de usuario.
Tengo entendido que primero he de crear un JFrame y después un JPanel, como si de un portatapapeles en el que fuéramos poniendo láminas se tratara. Una vez hecho esto, se pueden poner botones, cuadros de texto y todo tipo de componentes swing dentro de ese JPanel.
Bien yo creo una clase Marco que hereda de JFrame:
package com.mtpa.interfazUsuario;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class MarcoLogin
        extends JFrame
{
    public MarcoLogin()
    {
        setBounds(600,300,280,350);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Login");
            
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        
        LaminaLogin lamina = new LaminaLogin();
        add(lamina);
        
    }
}

Y a continuación hago lo propio con una clase que he denominado lámina que hereda de JPanel:
package com.mtpa.interfazUsuario;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class LaminaLogin 
        extends JPanel
{
    public LaminaLogin()
    {
        campo1 = new JTextField(20);
        add(campo1);
        
        miBoton = new JButton("Haz click");
        EventoBoton recuperarTexto = new EventoBoton();
        miBoton.addActionListener(recuperarTexto);
        add(miBoton);
    }
    
    private class EventoBoton 
            implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            System.out.println(campo1.getText().trim());
        }
    }
    
    private final JTextField campo1;
    private final JButton miBoton;
}

Este sencillo ejemplo tendría que permitirme introducir un texto dentro del JTextField campo 1 y que al pulsar el botón miboton se imprimiera por consola el texto introducido.
El resultado, no obstante, es el siguiente:

Parece que el marco se crea correctamente, es más, hasta aparece el título de la ventana, pero luego no tengo ni idea de por qué no se ve el JPanel...

debes agregar    this.setVisible(true); despues de añadir el objeto al frame no antes

Hace ya la leche que no uso swing pero si no me equivoco no estás indicándole qué layout debe utilizar, así que tienes el layout por defecto, que calcula los tamaños de los objetos y su ubicación al llamar a pack() en tu frame.
